# a monthly salary of $2,000 less tax and insurance (real salary after deducting tax and insurance,,,)

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

a monthly salary of $2,000 less tax and insurance

real salary that we receive after deducting tax and insurance? or we should still deduct tax and insurance from $2,000 ?

ps. I feel in reality the second one is the answer but logically I think the first interpretation is better. And also think it's kind of marketing purporse by the job ads posters to make it look bigger.

Comment: Answer to what??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Less' in this context means 'minus' or 'before deductions'.

> '50 less 14' equals 36.

If the monthly salary is $2,000 and you pay 10% tax, 10% pension contributions, and 10% health insurance, you get paid 70% of $2,000 in your bank account, that is $1,400. The amount before deductions (the $2,000) is often called the 'gross' amount, and the amount you actually have to spend (the $1,400) is often called the 'net' amount. Likewise if you want to buy something costing $1,000 **less** a 10% discount, (e.g. for paying promptly) you have to pay $900.

> less
> preposition
> **minus**:
> *The total is 30 dollars, **less** the five dollars deposit that you paid.*

[Less (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/less)

In the dictionary example above, the amount to be paid is $25.

It is logical and sensible for employers to quote salaries as gross amounts because not all employees pay the same rate of tax and insurance. In my country, you have a tax-free allowance of 12,000 per year (in round figures). If you earn more than that, you pay 20% tax until you earn 50,000. Then you pay 40% on the earnings over that. So someone taking a second job or who has a separate income (e.g. from investments or pensions) might pay more tax than someone who did not have those. Also if you are over a certain age you don't pay State unemployment contributions. For these reasons, a person considering applying for a job looks at the gross figure.